# Pyramid with memcached: how to make it work? Error - MissingCacheParameter: url is required

Tags: python, memcached, pyramid, beaker

I have site on Pyramid framework and want to cache with memcached. For testing reasons I've used memory type caching and everything was OK. I'm using `pyramid_beaker` package.
Here is my previous code (working version).

In `.ini` file

```
cache.regions = day, hour, minute, second
cache.type = memory
cache.second.expire = 1
cache.minute.expire = 60
cache.hour.expire = 3600
cache.day.expire = 86400
```

In views.py:

```
from beaker.cache import cache_region

@cache_region('hour')
def get_popular_users():
    #some code to work with db
return some_dict
```

The only `.ini` settings I've found in docs were about working with memory and file types of caching. But I need to work with memcached.

First of all I've installed package `memcached` from Ubuntu official repository and also `python-memcached` to my virtualenv.

In `.ini` file I've replaced `cache.type = memory` -> `cache.type = memcached`. And I've got next error:

> **beaker.exceptions.MissingCacheParameter**
>
> MissingCacheParameter: url is required

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, using the [TurboGears documentation](http://turbogears.org/2.1/docs/main/Caching.html) as a guide, what settings do you have for the url?

```
[app:main]
beaker.cache.type = ext:memcached
beaker.cache.url = 127.0.0.1:11211
# you can also store sessions in memcached, should you wish
# beaker.session.type = ext:memcached
# beaker.session.url = 127.0.0.1:11211
```

It looks to me as if [memcached requires a url](https://github.com/tav/pylibs/blob/master/beaker/ext/memcached.py) to initialize correctly:

```
def __init__(self, namespace, url=None, data_dir=None, lock_dir=None, **params):
    NamespaceManager.__init__(self, namespace)

    if not url:
        raise MissingCacheParameter("url is required")
```

I am not really sure why the code allows url to be optional (defaulting to None) and then requires it. I think it would have been simpler just to require the url as an argument.

---

Later: in response to your next question:

> when I used cache.url I've got next error: AttributeError:
>   'MemcachedNamespaceManager' object has no attribute 'lock_dir'

I'd say that the way I read the code below, you have to provide either `lock_dir` or `data_dir` to initialize self.lock_dir:

```
    if lock_dir:
        self.lock_dir = lock_dir
    elif data_dir:
        self.lock_dir = data_dir + "/container_mcd_lock"
    if self.lock_dir:
        verify_directory(self.lock_dir)
```

You can replicate that exact error using this test code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, lock_dir=None, data_dir=None):
        if lock_dir:
            self.lock_dir = lock_dir
        elif data_dir:
            self.lock_dir = data_dir + "/container_mcd_lock"
        if self.lock_dir:
            verify_directory(self.lock_dir)

f = Foo()
```

It turns out like this:

```
>>> f = Foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in __init__
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'lock_dir'
```

Comment: when I used cache.url I've got next error: `AttributeError: 'MemcachedNamespaceManager' object has no attribute 'lock_dir'`

Comment: And in my code url is required def _ _init__(self, namespace, url, memcache_module='auto', data_dir=None, lock_dir=None, **kw):

Comment: When I've added `lock_dir` everything started to work fine. But why memcached requires that directory? It is memory cache, not files cache...